# Whats wrong here with this?

Tags: mysql, symfony

What's wrong here please

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
    roles JSON NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cognome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB'
```

this is the error:

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, cognome VARCHAR(255) N  
  OT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':                                                                                

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR  
  (255) NOT NULL, nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, cogno' at line 1
```

Comment: What is the returned error message?

Comment: Might something to do with JSON data type. MairaDB does not have implementation for such data type

Comment: As @triplem describe, please, provide with the error you are receiving from the MySQL engine.

Comment: As it will be the same, have you tried to set array and not json in your entity? Also, a quote is missing around `InnoDB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON datatype seems not to be implemented on MariaDB database.
According to MariaDB website 
JSON is an alias to `LONGTEXT`

See [JSON DATATYPE - MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)

You can instead use `varchar` or `text` or `LONGTEXT` datatype.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
    roles VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cognome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: well this worked for me i had a database i had made in mysql 8 but when  i imported into myphpAdmin  i had error as it uses MariaDb